# How to get the Directories from the filepath excluding the root and filename

Tags: c#

I have a filepath say "C:\hello\hi\dotnet\abc.txt". I just want the directories from the path.

Expected Output :

```
hello
hi
dotnet
```

I have used `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` but it doesn't work.So help me out to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use (**EDIT as per comments**)

```
string YourFilePath = @"C:\hello\hi\dotnet\abc.txt";
string[] YourResult = Path.GetDirectoryName (YourFilePath).Split (new char[] {Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}).Skip(1).ToArray();
```

And this is the result:

`YourResult[0]` contains hello
`YourResult[1]` contains hi
`YourResult[2]` contains dotnet

For MSDN references see:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx

Comment: Yahia, the code works fine when i don't include Skip(1) i.e string[] YourResult = Path.GetDirectoryName (YourFilePath).Split (new char[] {Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}) but when I include Skip(1) it giver me error that Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: changed it... see the EDIT and the alternative... please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any answer that was of help...

Answer (score 2):

How about using string.Split and ignore the first and last items in the array?

Answer (score 2):

How about: -

```
string filename = @"C:\hello\hi\dotnet\abc.txt";
string dirName = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);   // C:\hello\hi\dotnet
string pathRoot = Path.GetPathRoot(dirName);        // C:\
string result = dirName.Substring(pathRoot.Length); // hello\hi\dotnet
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function

```
IEnumerable<string> GetDirectories(string path)
{                        
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);

    yield return di.Name;
    if (di.Parent == null)
       yield break;
    foreach (var dir in GetDirectories(di.Parent.FullName))
    {
       yield return dir;
    }           
}
```

using:

```
string path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
foreach(var dir in GetDirectories(path).Reverse())
      Console.WriteLine(dir);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (string s in System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName (path).Split(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Skip(1))
{
   //output
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can Do

```
string filePath="C:\\DocumentsAndSettings\\Users\\Xyz\\Downloads\\abc.txt";
filePath=Path.GetFullPath(filePath);
var split =filePath.Split('\\');
var sp = split.Take(split.Length - 1);
foreach ( var st in sp)
{
     Console.WriteLine(st);
}
```